# Nginx Ingress Rewrite Rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a spring microservice running on k8s having 2 API URL's.

1. First is `/api/actuator` for health check - running on port 9010
2. Second is `/api` for all other api calls - running on port 9000

I have created `ClusterIP` service to expose them on respective Ports.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: main-port
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  - name: health-port
    port: 9010
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9010
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

Now I want to create an Ingress on top of this Service which follows path based routing.

Any request like `/myapp/api/actuator/anything` should be rewritten as `/api/actuator/anything` (same what comes from original request).

For instance `/myapp/api/actuator/health` should be rewritten as /api/actuator/health`.

Any request like `/myapp/api/anything` should be rewritten as `/api/anything` (same what comes from original request).

For instance `/myapp/api/v1/getID/{id}` should be rewritten as `/api/v1/getID/{id}`.

I am facing difficulty in writing the rewrite rule for the same.
So far I could only come up with following rule as of now:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitops-lkart-api
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/$1
spec:
 rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp/api/actuator/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-svc
          servicePort: 9010
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp/api/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

But this would only work for `/api` paths and not for actuator.

Please recommend what rule should be written to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you need "- path: /myapp/api/(actuator/.*) ?

Comment: Is your problem still unresolved?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitops-lkart-api-1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/actuator/$1
spec:
 rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp/api/actuator/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-svc
          servicePort: 9010
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitops-lkart-api-2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/$1
spec:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp/api/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

You can create 2 independent ingresses.

If traffic hits on `/myapp/api/actuator/anything` it will be rewritten to `/api/actuator/anything`.

In other situation if traffic hits on `/myapp/api/anything` it will be rewritten to `/api/anything`.

Comment: Hello @VibhorJain and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!